# How to set the default timezone in PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

The default timezone is currently set to `UTC`. How to replace that default value? I am using PostgreSQL running on top of Amazon RDS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ALTER DATABASE <db_name>
  SET TimeZone = 'UTC';`

But you shouldn't do that. Using UTC for database is safest thing possible.

Comment: it is the only solution if all the users are on the same single timezone